# I created a mssql-server-linux container in Docker, but I can't connect from outside the container

Tags: sql-server, docker

I created a mssql-server-linux container in Docker that maps to port 4000 on the host.

Now, I'm connecting to this database, but I'm having an error.

How can i solve this problem?

> #### Error message
>
> `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or could not be accessed. Verify that the instance name is correct, and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:named Pipes provider, error:40-Unable to open connection to SQL Server)`
>   
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ETru.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check your server port in iptables if it is in ACCEPT state. Maybe your server is blocking or rejecting others.
And try to ping your server ip to check if you can reach the server.

This is the first troubleshooting when i tried connecting Docker containers in MongoDB.

Thanks!